# Multi way Communication, wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

In my scenario i have an application that has a service for other applications, this application is service host and named "mainApp", and i have n applications they has own services and host application can call a method from each one.
All other applications know host ip address and can call a method from it, but host application don't knows other applications addresses.
I found peer to peer and duplex clients in stackover,weblogs and msdn but i think they are no way to solving my scenario,i found codes likes following codes:
 in Clients:

```
                    factory =
                    new DuplexChannelFactory<IChatChannel>(context, "ChatEndPoint");
                    channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

in server (main service host)

```
            cprs = new CustomPeerResolverService();
            cprs.RefreshInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            host = new ServiceHost(cprs);
            cprs.ControlShape = true;
            cprs.Open();
            host.Open(TimeSpan.FromDays(1000000));
            lblMessage.Text = "Server started successfully.";
```

I want the mainApp can call a method from all other application's service or call a method from one other application without sending message to all other applications.
I am new in WCF programming and i don't have any idea to solve this scenario with wcf, pleas suggest me any idea.
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking, but if your clients have some sort of check-in call that they make to the main application, then the main application can obtain a call-back delegate from the client call context that it can subsequently use to make calls back to the client.